# gVim 7.4 for Windows, Windows 7: Windowing issues and mouse weirdness

Tags: vim, configuration, editor

Out of nowhere, I started having weird issues with gVim. Here's a short list:

- When I try to move the window with my mouse, clicking the title bar puts vim into Insert mode, and the window won't move.
- Sometimes, if I click again, vim goes back into Command mode. Sometimes it doesn't.
- Sometimes, the window moves. Sometimes, it doesn't.
- Sometimes, clicking the title bar and dragging highlights text.
- Sometimes, when I try to switch back to Insert mode and insert text wherever my cursor is, the cursor jumps to the beginning of the line.

What's killing me is that I haven't made any changes to my vimrc or gvimrc. This happened out of nowhere.

I reinstalled gVim, and nothing changed.

Here's my gvimrc, which lives on disk at `C:\Users\jpavlick\_gvimrc`:

```
colors desert
set guifont=Consolas
set guioptions=m
set guioptions=t

set listchars=tab:>-,nbsp:-
set list
```

Here's my vimrc, which lives on disk at `C:\Users\jpavlick\_vimrc`:

```
set nu
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set backspace=indent,eol,start
syntax on
set autoindent
au BufReadPost *.cshtml set syntax=html
au BufReadPost *.edi set syntax=edifile
au BufReadPost *.sql set syntax=tsql
autocmd Filetype ruby setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like a problem with Vim or its config. Do you use any invasive system tools like AutoHotkey scripts?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat nope, nothing at all. pure development machine running windows 7 with very few programs installed, imaged maybe 2 months ago. it's my work machine.